# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нет идей почему это не работает. Пытался перезапустить, менял папку, запускал от администратора, проверил документацию. По-моему все сделал правильно, но все равно не работает.

Python 3.7.6 (CPython). Windows 10

*Код*:

```
string = 'Text'

print(string.startwith('Text'))
```

*Traceback:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\%FOLDER%\%FILENAME%.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(string.startwith('Text'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Между t и w не хватает s - `startswith()`.